# Using Batch normalization with MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy on CloudML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am currently using `tensorflow-1.14` and using the `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy` on AI Platform training with a 3d Convolutional Network. Since AI Platform training doesn't officially support 1.14, I am adding `tensorflow-1.14` as a dependency to get the strategy working.
The issue is that when i try to use batch normalization is the code I run into issues while using group normalization (from the contrib package) runs smoothly.

Is the `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy` supposed to work smoothly on CMLE at all or is there something which I am missing?

```
def conv(
    inputs, is_training, filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1),
    padding='same', activation_fn='relu'):

  """ Function for 3D Convolution. """
  conv = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs, filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                          strides=strides, padding=padding)

  bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv, training=is_training)

  if activation_fn == None:
    out = bn

  else:
    out = tf.nn.relu6(bn)

  return out
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: From /job:chief/replica:0/task:0: Lower bound check fail for input 4 from node gradients/F9/e-3/batch_normalization_24/batchnorm/add_1_grad/Sum_1 to node scoped_allocator_concat_424_31 input bounds = [0x7fcae8cce500, 0x7fcae8cce600] backing_tensor bounds = [0x7fcae8f5fb00, 0x7fcae8fe0f88] [[{{node scoped_allocator_concat_424_31}}]]
```

Comment: As you mention I don't see TF 1.14 supported in CMLE yet. I don't believe the existing TF version gets upgraded by just adding it as a dependency. https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list does this work in TF 1.13 ? For unsupported training you should use containers feature: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/tensorflow/containers/unsupported_runtime

Comment: I will look into the container based training, but I believe the underlying tensorflow gets updated. Because the MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy API does not exist in 1.13. And since I can see the code running with that strategy I am assuming that it has changed.

Comment: Hi @VishalPagidipally.  The error you encountered appears to be from the underlying c++ code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/scoped_allocator_ops.cc#L139

It might be worth trying the custom container training as pointed out in the comment above.

Comment: @VishalPagidipally TF 1.14 runtime is now officially supported on AI Platform Training: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list . Could you give it a try and let us know if it works?

Comment: @dizcology, Sure. This workstream went cold for a while. But will pick it up and see if it works now.